# How to change the unit of timestamp from milliseconds to microseconds in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am new to Apache IoTDB, noticing that default unit of time series timestamps time are in milliseconds. I wonder if it can be changed to nano-second or etc... how can I achieve this?

Document should have included it, but I did not find it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will have to reconfigure IoTDB

- in IoTDB config file(typically `iotdb-engine.properties`) you can adjust timestamp precision
- the parameter might be called `time_precision` | `time_unit` | add it new
- `time_precision = us` or `time_unit = us`
- save the configuration and restart the IoTDB service

Ps, specific configuration options and names depend on versions

Answer (score 3):

Datatypes of timestamps in Apache IoTDB are divided into two types: `LONG` and `DATETIME` (including `DATETIME-INPUT` and `DATETIME-DISPLAY`). `DATETIME` type can set the timestamps to be displayed in microseconds, so you can try to change your timestamp datatype.